# Math with MySQL timestamps in groovy

Tags: math, time, groovy

I need to subtract one timestamp from another in groovy and get the number of hours that has passed. The timestamps are coming from MySQL. When I do simple math I get numbers of days rounded off to zero integers.

endDate - startDate
gives rounded integer

I want a result of 2.35 hours, etc.

Comment: _SELECT (endDate - startDate)/60 FROM table_ does return the good result ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groovy.time.TimeCategory` like so:

```
// create two timestamps
import java.sql.Timestamp

def dates = ['2012/08/03 09:00', '2012/08/03 10:30']
def (Timestamp a, Timestamp b) = dates.collect {
  new Timestamp( Date.parse( 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm', it ).time )
}

// Then compare them with TimeCategory
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
  def duration = b - a
  println "${duration.days}d ${duration.hours}h ${duration.minutes}m"
}
```

Which will print:

```
0d 1h 30m
```