# What do empty square brackets after a variable name mean in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I'm fairly new to groovy, looking at some existing code, and I see this:

```
def timestamp = event.timestamp[]
```

I don't understand what the empty square brackets are doing on this line. Note that the timestamp being def'd here should receive a long value.

In this code, `event` is defined somewhere else in our huge code base, so I'm not sure what it is. I thought it was a map, but when I wrote some separate test code using this notation on a map, the square brackets result in an empty value being assigned to timestamp. In the code above, however, the brackets are necessary to get correct (non-null) values.

Some quick Googling didn't help much (hard to search on "[]").

EDIT: Turns out event and event.timestamp are both zero.core.groovysupport.GCAccessor objects, and as the answer below says, the [] must be calling getAt() on these objects and returning a value (in this case, a long).

Comment: `event.getClass()` returns...? Can you run the code? What class is the `timestamp` object?

Comment: What is 'the correct value' that you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets will invoke the underlying `getAt(Object)` method of that object, so that line is probably invoking that one.

I made a small script:

```
class A { 
    def getAt(p) { 
        println "getAt: $p"
        p 
    }
}
def a = new A()
b = a[]
println b.getClass()
```

And it returned the value passed as a parameter. In this case, an `ArrayList`. Maybe that timestamp object has some metaprogramming on it. What does `def timestamp` contains after running the code?

Also check your groovy version.

Answer (score 0):

Empty list, found [this](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections). Somewhat related/possibly helpful [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785134/math-with-mysql-timestamps-in-groovy).

Answer (score 0):

Not at a computer, but that looks like it's calling the method `event.timestamp` and passing an empty list as a parameter.

The same as:

```
def timestamp = event.timestamp( [] )
```